# CSS background animation

Tags: css, animation

I need to make this animation as a background:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yu1kot89f05ybgn/Comp%201_10.mov?dl=0

I've tried to do it with image:

```
background-image url('../images/content/fracture.png')
animation background-moving linear 10s infinite;
```

But animation from video is more complicated.

What technology should be used here? (CSS, SVG-animation...)?
Or provide please some examples.

Comment: This might help you to get started http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Comment: You can also use sprite animation

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give some options to you based on my experience.

- Have a `GIF file` and set the background (easiest)
- Get a PNG/SVG With 3 hills, add animate the background based on `CSS animation` & `CSS transition` (works)
- Simply add a video based on `HTML5 video` tags. Many sites does that. (But, based on the video you shared, this is unnecessary.)
- Have a canvas as background & write `JavaScript` that loops the transition (complex)